# Why is the output inverted for this SPICE model

Tags: ltspice, spice

I created a part from the SPICE code of a [4n32](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81865/4n324n33.pdf). I found the SPICE code from [here](http://ltwiki.org/files/LTspiceIV/Vendor%20List/Spice-Models-collection/opto.lib).

And here is the section about this part:

```
*******************************************************************************
* A = diode anode
* K = diode cathode
* C = BJT collector
* B = BJT base
* E = BJT emitter
.SUBCKT A4N32 A K C B E PARAMS: REL_CTR=1
* 4N32 from Motorola Optoelectronics data book Q3/93  -  RPerez
D1 A D Demit   ;Gallium arsenide infrared emitting diode
Vsense D K 0    ;Diode Current sense -> IF
* Gpcg models CTR 
Gpcg C B TABLE  ;Photodetector {IC@IF * (normalized CTR at IF)/(Q1 BF)
+ {70m*REL_CTR*(8.448148613*0.998979389^(1/(abs(I(Vsense))+0.1p))*
+ I(Vsense)^0.449371295)/18k} (0,0) (0.3m,0.3m)
Q1 C B V Qdtect1   ;phototransistor detector
Q2 C V E E Qdtect2   ;Darlington
.model Demit D IS=1P N=1.948621 RS=1.560495 BV=3 IBV=0.05U
+ CJO=18.8P VJ=0.532794 M=0.27985 EG=1.424 TT=500N
.model Qdtect1 NPN IS=0.625P BF=135 NF=1.0941401 BR=10 TF=0 TR=1.2u
+ CJE=8.24P VJE=0.99 MJE=0.247851 CJC=8.01P VJC=0.514483 MJC=0.370451
+ ISC=0 VAF=275 IKF=0  ISE=0.1p
.model Qdtect2 NPN IS=0.625P BF=135 NF=1.0941401 BR=10 TF=0 TR=1.2u
+ CJE=8.24P VJE=0.99 MJE=0.247851
+ ISC=0 VAF=275 IKF=0  ISE=0.1p ISS=0 CJS=3.82p VJS=0.99 MJS=0.200397
.ends
*$
*******************************************************************************
```

Then I use this part in the following circuit:

[image]

The pin number assignment are are:

[image]

What could be the reason that the output is inverted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LTspice, exponentiation is `**`, not `^` (which is meant as XOR). Just search and replace the two occurences of it. Instead of:

`+ {70m*REL_CTR*(8.448148613*0.998979389^(1/(abs(I(Vsense))+0.1p))*
+ I(Vsense)^0.449371295)/18k} (0,0) (0.3m,0.3m)`

have:

`+ {70m*REL_CTR*(8.448148613*0.998979389**(1/(abs(I(Vsense))+0.1p))*
+ I(Vsense)**0.449371295)/18k} (0,0) (0.3m,0.3m)`